# How to compose fragments from an array of relay containers?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relayjs

I'm building an instant messenger feature into a project of mine. The project uses React and Relay. The instant messenger feature is similar to Facebook chat, where you can see a list of people to talk to and clicking on a person will open a chat window for that one-on-one discussion.

In my implementation, the user list, of who you can chat with, is separated from the list of opened chat windows. So, the user list is not actually important to this question.

Regarding the rendering of the open chat windows, my approach to this has been to create a parent React Component / Relay Container. This parent component will keep track of which chat windows the user has opened, and will build the array of chat window React Components and finally render them. This list of open chat windows is all local state within the parent React Component.

The individual chat window React Component / Relay Container has a fragment that queries from a parameterized field, where the parameter is the id of the user that the chat window's discussion is with. So, if this chat window is for a discussion with Bob, it'll be Bob's id.

With that all in mind, here's an example parent component implementation ...

```js
class FloatingDiscussionPane extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.renderDiscussions()}
      </ul>
    );
  }

  renderDiscussions() {
    const {teamIds} = this.props;
    return teamIds.map(teamId => {
      return (
        <FloatingDiscussionPaneDiscussion
          teamId={teamId} />
      );
    });
  }
};

export default Relay.createContainer(FloatingDiscussionPane, {
  fragments: {
    session: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Session {
        ${/* how to get fragments from the array of discussion windows */}
      }
    `
  }
});
```

And here would be an example implementation of the chat window ...

```js
class FloatingDiscussionPaneDiscussion extends React.Component {
  render() {
    ...
  }
};

export default Relay.createContainer(FloatingDiscussionPaneDiscussion, {
  fragments: {
    session: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Session {
        messages: myDiscussionMessages(team: $teamId) {
          ...
        }
      }
    `
  }
});
```

As you can see, the `FloatingDiscussionPaneDiscussion` container has a fragment that needs to be included in the parent container, `FloatingDiscussionPane`. The parent component, `FloatingDiscussionPane`, will have an array of `FloatingDiscussionPaneDiscussion` though, all needing to have their own fragments included in the parent fragment.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I will assume for a moment that your schema is such that teams have messages (a plural field, backed by a `GraphQLList`) and sessions have teams.

The pane component can load up all the teams and their nested messages.

```js
class FloatingDiscussionPane extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.renderDiscussions()}
      </ul>
    );
  }

  renderDiscussions() {
    const {session: {teams}} = this.props;
    return teams.map(({id, messages}) => {
      return (
        <li key={id}>
          <FloatingDiscussionPaneDiscussion messages={messages} />
        </li>
      );
    });
  }
};

export default Relay.createContainer(FloatingDiscussionPane, {
  fragments: {
    session: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Session {
        teams {
          id
          ${FloatingDiscussionPaneDiscussion.getFragment('team')}
        }
      }
    `,
  },
});
```

And each pane can consume those messages and display them:

```js
class FloatingDiscussionPaneDiscussion extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {team: {messages}} = this.props;
    return (
      <ul>
        {messages.map(({id, text, sender: {name: senderName}}) => 
          <li key={id}>{senderName}: {text}</li>
        )}
      </ul>
    );
  }
};

export default Relay.createContainer(FloatingDiscussionPaneDiscussion, {
  fragments: {
    team: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Team {
        messages {
          id
          recipient { name }
          sender { name }
          text
        }
      }
    `,
  },
});
```

Comment: The component hierarchy above is a bit coarse. You'll likely want to break it own such that you have an App, a Team, a Discussion, and a Message component, each owning its own small part of the fragment tree.